# Why does EasyJet require my ID details in advance?

Tags: air-travel, uk, identity-cards, easyjet

I truly wonder why does EasyJet need to know my ID details in advance for my flight from Prague to London:

[image]

It is a requirement of UK customs? If so, why haven't I been asked this information for my EuroStar ticket from Paris to London?

Comment: one point, they ASSERT that they are "required to do so".  (this may or may not be Truth, but it's a starting point..)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UK is indeed among the countries requiring “[Advance Passenger Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System)” according to Wikipedia, although I don't recall ever needing to enter my passport details in advance (last time I went there must be a couple of years ago).

Trains are treated differently, probably because you have to clear immigration in France or Belgium, before boarding the train. Not so with air travel: You will be on board long before any contact with the British authorities and are already on UK territory when approaching UK border control. Furthermore, planes come to the UK from all sorts of far away places, not only a couple of friendly and (mostly) reliable countries.

Comment: Actually, I would suspect that the information is recorded by Eurostar personal at check-in time as well, just that this check in procedure happens at the train station, and not at home.

Comment: @DCTLib I haven't done it recently but I believe Eurostar doesn't need to do anything, you meet actual UKBA officers (or whatever they are called nowadays) in Paris. It's possible Eurostar shares data anyway, especially regarding exits.

Comment: @DCTLib Eurostar staff don't see your passport, and don't ask for it when booking. Heading from Europe to the UK, your passport is checked by French or Belgian immigration officers (Schengen exit) then immediately by British ones (UK juxtaposed entry), but never Eurostar